# Change json data from local list to online file

Tags: android, mysql, json, api, flutter

I have this list of data as a **String**, I want to store it in a JSON file and call it as a **String** again to keep it in **List**,
but it throws an error because of data types

here is the code

```
import 'package:project/models/Response.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
final body ='''
[
  {
    "urlToImage": "assets/images/spelt_noodles.png",
    "title": "Biona Organic Spelt Noodles",
    "price": 2.99,
    "weight": 250,
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-07-07 10:44:53",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-07 10:44:53"
  },
  {
    "urlToImage": "assets/images/spelt_spaghetti.png",
    "title": "Biona Organic Spelt Noodles",
    "price": 2.99,
    "weight": 250,
    "id": 2,
    "created_at": "2019-07-07 10:44:53",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-07 10:44:53"
  },
  {
    "urlToImage": "assets/images/spelt_noodles.png",
    "title": "Biona Organic Spelt Noodles",
    "price": 2.99,
    "weight": 250,
    "id": 3,
    "created_at": "2019-07-07 10:44:53",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-07 10:44:53"
  }
]''';

class ProductsRepository{


    List<Product>  fetchAllProducts() {

    var jsonB = (jsonDecode(body) as List).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    var list = jsonB.map<Response1>((e) => Response1.fromJson(e)).toList();

     List<Product> items = [];

      for (var item in list) {
        items.add(new Product(item.urlToImage, item.title, item.price, item.price, item.id));
      }

    return items;

  }
```

I tried

```
  var response;
  String data;
  Future<String> getData() {
    response = http.get('https://example.json');
    return data = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

  }
```

But it throws an error,
So how can I get the json file by http and convert it to string to give it to the jsonDecode(**body**)?

Comment: You can update the question with error message please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.body` is already a String, you don't need to do anything.

```dart
Future<String> getData() async {
  response = await http.get('https://example.json');
  return response.body;
}
```

Comment: yeah but I'm facing problem with loading the json file
it takes a few seconds to download but flutter doesn't wait for it, it executes the next lines of codes and returns **String** as **Null**

Comment: The difference between your code and my example is in mine, getData is an async function, and I am using await to wait for the http.get to complete.